# UIButton added to UICollectionViewCell doesn't respond in iOS 7.1 but works on iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, ios8, uicollectionview, ios7.1

I have a UICollectionView and I have a custom cell with a reusable view. I have a button inside the cell and it works fine on iOS 8.0 but doesn't work on iOS 7.1. I tried bringSubViewToFront and that didn't work. I am not sure why it would work on iOS 8.0 and not on 7.1

Update:

Trying the same with Xcode 5 had the issue resolved. But going back to Xcode 6 I have the issue.

Comment: oddly enough I have the opposite situation. I have a UITextField and a UIButton in a cell that don't respond in iOS8 but work fine in iOS7

Comment: So I am assuming somehow the touch events are not responding. I will add hit tests to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Xcode 6.1 has fixed the issue. So I assume Xcode 6.0 was the reason that 7.1 had issues.

Comment: I'm still getting my issue with 6.1... not making any sense

Comment: I'm having the same problem (UIButton inside a UICollectionViewCell), where the UIButton not catching clicks in iOS7.1 (it previously did) yet on iOS8 it works fine. upgrading Xcode to 6.1 didn't help.. any other suggestions ?

Comment: @BenGoodwin can you try bringing the button view to front programatically

Comment: Problem solved, upgrading to 6.1 did fix the problem after all. Thanx.